# JIRA: can a jira issue be moved out from done?

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

I moved by mistake a issue from not started to DONE. Is there a way to move back the issue?

I would rather let it "in progress".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, but you may have to customize your workflow to add a transition from the DONE status to another status. Make sure to clear the resolution using a post function so that your issue key is not marked with a strike through

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Or no, or maybe :)

It depends on your issue type's workflow, but you can *usually* re-open the issue and set it to in-progress.

This, of course, may also be dependent on

1. What version of JIRA you're using
2. If you're using GreenHopper/JIRA Agile
3. If you have a custom issue workflow/lifecycle
4. What your user permissions are.

Any additional details about your JIRA instance might be helpful! Is it a hosted ( ala Atlassian on-demand ) or on-prem, etc.